# appending date in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe as follows:

```
           Dates
0     2001-01-01
1     2001-01-02
2     2001-01-03
3     2001-01-04
```

I want to append 2 consecutive dates and get the following dataframe.

```
           Dates
0     2001-01-01
1     2001-01-02
2     2001-01-03
3     2001-01-04
4     2001-01-05
5     2001-01-06


new = pd.date_range(dates.Dates.iloc[-1], periods=2)
print (new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), but necessary remove first new value by indexing `[1:]`:

```
new = pd.date_range(df.Dates.iloc[-1], periods=3)
s = pd.Series(new[1:])
new = df['Dates'].append(s, ignore_index=True)
print (new)
0   2001-01-01
1   2001-01-02
2   2001-01-03
3   2001-01-04
4   2001-01-05
5   2001-01-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
new = pd.date_range(df.Dates.iloc[-1], periods=3)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(new[1:], columns=['Dates'])
df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
       Dates
0 2001-01-01
1 2001-01-02
2 2001-01-03
3 2001-01-04
4 2001-01-05
5 2001-01-06
```

Or recontruct `DataFrame`:

```
new = pd.date_range(df.Dates.iloc[0], periods=len(df) + 2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(new, columns=['Dates'])
print (df1)
       Dates
0 2001-01-01
1 2001-01-02
2 2001-01-03
3 2001-01-04
4 2001-01-05
5 2001-01-06
```

Comment: i want to append the index as well, 0 to 5

Comment: @ian just do `new.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)`.

Comment: @shivsn AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Comment: @ian - not necessary, `ignore_index=True` help it.